# Use port 995 for MYSQL on ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: server, 20.04, mysql, database

In my MYSQL configuration file, when I replace port 3060 (original) by 995, that don't work, when I `service mysql restart`, I have:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

But when I replace 3060 by 5671 for example, that work, no error and my remote connection with port 5671 works!

So by searching, I find that we can't put a port < 1024... but I have to put an inferior one, how can we procced?

Comment: Please check your OS & release details. There were no Ubuntu releases in 2020-June (ie. 20.06)

Comment: Why do you want a restricted port ? Ports below 1024 are restricted and requires elevated privileges to use. And how do you start mysql ?

Comment: Thanks for answering ! Because I have to connect from WordPress to an external server, and WP only allow outbound traffic from 465, 587, 110, 995, 143, 993, 80 or 443.

Comment: Sorry That was 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soren is correct that ports below 1024 are restricted and requires elevated privileges. It's generally not a good idea to use ports under 1024 without a great deal of thought and planning ahead of time.

That said, if you absolutely *must* use a lower-numbered port, you can use `iptables` to redirect a lower-numbered port to the one the application is listening on.

For example:

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 995 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3306
```

Substitute 995 with the port to expose, and 3306 with the port your MySQL installation is listening on.

> **Note:**
> Port 995 is used with SSL-encrypted POP3 services for encrypted mail transfer. It is also used by mail servers such as NT's Exchange Server for user auth. Reusing port numbers under 1024 can lead to all sorts of unexpected problems down the road. Be *very* careful when circumventing intentional restrictions.

Comment: Yes because I have to connect from WordPress to an external server, and WP only allow outbound traffic from 465, 587, 110, 995, 143, 993, 80 or 443. And that's not a really great things as you say. I would prefer to use a upper one.

Comment: So your solution works, but that is not a great things I admit... what problem could appear by using 995 for MYSQL connexion ? Would there be a port below 1024 more suitable for a MYSQL connection?

Comment: Based on the things you're saying, I'm assuming that the MySQL server that you're connecting to is accessible to the entire Internet ... and you're using a non-standard port to get things working ... which is very, very sub-optimal. The most suitable port would be 3306 to a MySQL server that is accessible to the web servers and completely shielded from the Internet. A database server has no right to be connected to the open web, after all. You're just asking for trouble. There are always solutions, though. Put security first. The rest will follow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time ! So if I put a firewall on 995 (in my case) only allowing enter by the WP server, that should be secure and great ? Just, that's sure, I have to go out of WP !

Comment: Security for internet-connected devices involves a lot more than just firewalls and allowlists. I would *strongly* advise to putting the database on an internal network, accessible only to the web servers.

Comment: I do agree mith you, that's my final goal. But for moment, I can't, I will do that later. Thank you very much for your help !